# Create new pandas data frame of subset of columns using each tuple value in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, tuples

I have a list  named combo=[('A','B'),('A','B','C')] , now I want to create a new data frame sub setting the column names from each tuple value in the list.
df is the original data frame and data_abr will every time create new data frame with the column names from tuples in the list. 'A', 'B' , 'C' are column names. Pretty much new to python , any idea's how to access those tuple names as columns in the dataframe

```
for idx in range(len(combo)):

   data_abr = df.loc[:,[combo[i]dx].values
   data_abr_pd=pd.DataFrame(data_abr)
```

Output:
**Iteration 1:**

[image]

**Iteration 2 :**

[image]

Comment: Your first item in the list, `('A')`, is not actually a tuple, because it needs to have a trailing comma: `('A',)`. Isn't *that* what you intended?

Comment: Yes, that's my intented question

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you just need

```py
combo=[('A','B'),('A','B','C')]

for cols in combo:
    data_abr_pd = df[list(cols)]
    print(data_abr_pd)
```